# Disable Rstudio viewer

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, tmap

I am working with the `tmap` package and want to produce `leaflet` maps (with `tmap_mode("view")`). Rstudio crashes quite often when I try this.

How can I force Rstudio (or only the "plotting" function) to display the output rather in the browser than in the intern viewer.

Comment: `options(viewer=NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call a plot window that is used instead of the Rstudio viewer with the `windows` command on Windows or with `quartz` (mac) or `x11` (linux).

Comment: I want to open it in a extern browser and not in the plot window.

Comment: @Alex This opens a new window like in basic R, so it does work outside RStudio. It might not crash as often as RStudio. But the option from timelyportfolio works as well.